# How can I vertically center my logo with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a logo at http://listingnaples.com/ and I'm trying to vertically center the logo.

I have added:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

It still sits low in the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the styles for the image to a vertical transform and remove the padding from the parent anchor tag.

```
img {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This was fantastic, thanks!  The only slight change I made was to change the padding:0 to be only applied to top and bottom.